# non-linear equation, easy soltution?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there an easy way to show, that the only solution of this system of non-linear equations has only the solution a=0, b=0, c=0

$a+b+c=0$

$ax+by+cz=0$

$ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$

For $x,y,z\neq 0$ and different.

Solving this gets really ugly.
Is there an elegant way?
It is obvious that a=0, b=0, c=0 solves this, but how can I tell, that this is the only solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (a simple form of) Vandermonde determinant:
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
x & y & z \\
x^2 & y^2 & z^2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\det\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & y-x & z-x \\
0 & y^2-x^2 & z^2-x^2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\det\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & y-x & z-x \\
0 & 0 & z^2-x^2-(z-x)(y+x)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: And why is the only solution then a=0, b=0, c=0? Since x,y,z are not zero and different the determinant is not zero. But why does this mean we have only one solution?

Comment: @Cornman If the matrix of the system is invertible, there is one and only one solution.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $x,y,z \ne0$ and different, the $3\times 3$ matrix of the coefficients of $a,b,c$ (the unknowns in the given system) is invertibe.

Answer (score 1):

Vandermonde gives $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2z-x^2y)=(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$, which is not zero.